# Covering of Projective Space

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

Let $f: \mathbb{P}^1 _{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbb{P}^1  _{\mathbb{C}}$ be a map over $\mathbb{C}$ defined on homogeneous cordinates via

$$[x:y] \to [x^d:y^d]$$

for $d \ge 2$.

My question is why $f$ is a covering of degree $d$?

The main problem is to see why for example the point $[1:0]$ has $d$ preimages in $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Here occurs the problem that for the $d$-th primitive root of unity $\zeta$ all "preimages" $[\zeta^k:0]$ for $k$ integer, $0≤k<d$ are the same point in $\mathbb{P}^1 _{\mathbb{C}}$ by definition / construction of homogeneous coordinates.

Where is an error in my reasoning?

Comment: It might be an example of a _branched covering_ (ramified at $[1:0]$).

Comment: It's not a covering: (path-connected) coverings of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ are classified by the subgroupgs of $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}P^1) = \pi_1(S^2) = 0$: there is only (up to  isomorphism of coverings) the trivial covering $\mathbb{C}P^1\to \mathbb{C}P^1$

Comment: @Max Why not officially answer the question?